# How do I reverse-bias a resistor?

Tags: resistors, heat, bias, detector

We all know that a photo diode can be used as a light detector and as a light emitter (although the way that it's  built will usually make it specialized to prioritize one application over the other); an electric motor can become an electric generator and vice-versa.

How does one run a resistor in reverse bias (ie: turn heat into electricity, rather than electricity into heat)?

Something in my gut (but I had a hard time googling it) tells me that if I hold a resistor over a candle flame: it won't instantly become a little battery. So do I add an oscillating inductive coil around it; should I hold it over a candle but add a diode? I'm at a loss on this one.

Please note: I have like zero budget and no safe laboratory space for tinkering, so out of a general respect for my home: I have to avoid the funner flammable projects, so this  is why I need to ask dumb questions, because I'm prevented from experimenting; otherwise I wouldn't have bothered you all.

I'm asking: what is a resistor's true [secondary] output (other than reduced electrical current) (is it 'heat', or is it just some subatomic phenomenon that manifests as 'heat'), and how do I feed that back into a 'dead' [as in: "no current is flowing through it"] resistor to get an electrical current flow? What form would this hypothetical flow take? Would each metal contact of the resistor become negatively charged [with each metal end acting like its own 'mini-ground' from the resistance-induced ionization]?
(Internal friction can cause an electrical field, just like external friction can too right?)

I partially feel bad for asking [because it feels so elementary], but if I don't: I'll remain ignorant.

Thanks for your time

(I know this is April 1st in some parts, but I forgot, right after I typed out my whole question, so I'm gonna go out on a limb, and if I get accused of tomfoolery I'll just delete my question, and ask it on day that's not gonna net me suspicion (because I'm somewhat lazy and don't want to forget to ask on April 2nd))

Comment: That's not what "reverse bias" means....

Comment: Resistors don't work that way, due to entropy. There's no bias on a resistor, heat is lost regardless of what direction the current flows. What you want is called a Thermo-Electric Generator (TEG) and can be accomplished using a Peltier junction and appropriate heatsink. A Peltier junction is essentially an array of thermocouples, which transduces heat into voltage or voltage into heat. They're not very efficient, but they do convert some heat into voltage. TANSTAAFL, so no building perpetual motion machines with this tech.

Comment: even **if** a resistor could produce electric current when subjected to heat, there is nothing that would determine the direction of the current, so there would not be any net current

Comment: First, repeal the Second Law of Thermodynamics.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is you can't because physics.

The long answer is you can't because voltage is a **difference** of potential.

What you're looking for does exist. [Thermoelectric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator) translate a difference in heat into a difference of potential through the reactions between different materials.

A resistor is generally a fairly uniform material exposed to a fairly uniform ambient temperature. There isn't anything inherent to its construction that would allow for a difference of potential by apply a single temperature.

The heat that is produced is a waste product. The process can't simply be reversed. The dual action in some components is possible due to specific electromagnetic phenomena inherent to their physical construction, so we can't arbitrarily assume all components can be used to generate a voltage.

And it's a good thing too. If that were the case we would have to be worried about voltage spikes as soon as the power is removed as the heat is absorbed like a magnetic field collapsing around an inductor. And because all components generate heat, there would be no way to control for it. Creating a stable circuit would be impossible.

Comment: So, in response, I've known about TEGs and just assumed that they were like solid-state sterling engines and/or very IR sensitive solar panels; is that accurate?

Comment: Furthermore; if I could add a material gradient to a resistor, maybe, by slitting and adding an oriented heat-sink in some manner: could I get it to begin generating power through heat that way?

Comment: If I put an inductive coil around my resistor and passed an AC current through my inductive coil: would the resistor heat up faster or slower than an ordinary copper wire with the same inductor around (inductors transfer electrical current, that's a given, so now I'm just curious about how the inductive heating would shake-out), this method is kind of a "cheat" way of getting a resistor to generate power, but still

Comment: I upvoted you. I didn't touch the vote count on Tony Stewart's answer; I feel kinda like his troll comment was directed at me though. Not every "stupid" comment is from someone who believes in free energy, nor is every stupid person secretly a harvard proffessor pulling a dumb prank. Some people just legit don't know

Comment: @user179283 I don't think Tony's troll comment was directed at you, unless you were the one to initially down vote his answer without explanation. For whatever reason, I'm not seeing the up vote on mine, but I'm not all that concerned. Just hope it helped some.

Comment: My upvote went away because my rep went down, I wish people weren't so mean on here, but I digress

Comment: @user179283 No worries. For all your following questions, while I admire your curiosity I think you'll probably get much more out of googling "how does X work." I don't want to discourage basic questions and fundamental learning, but this community is best used as a last resort when you've hit the bottom of a research rabbit hole and are still confused by a specific issue.

Comment: I didn't but I thought they were anonymous (I'm on mobile), so I assumed that they had assumed since it was a vague comment, but maybe it is vague on purpose. I still am a bit sensitive to the word "troll" getting tossed around, since although it's a real threat on the internet, it tends to be a bit "witch-hunt-ee" and then feelings get hurt and discussions break down

Comment: @user179283 Can appreciate the sensitivity. Only tried to answer because it seemed that you were being sincere. You seem to have a healthy interest in the field and I applaud your enthusiasm. You also seem to have some knowledge of tertiary concepts, but could use some serious research into the fundamentals. How specific components work makes much more sense if you understand how basic electronics work. Maybe start with a free electronics course. [Here's](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/) one example of many for a good online electronics text book.

Comment: Phil C I meant to respond sooner: I have been the proud owner of "Circuit Analysis: Theory and Practice 4th edition by Allan H. Robbins, & Wilhelm C. Miller" for some time now [but I haven't dug in yet], in addition to this rudimentary Youtube-based surface knowledge: " https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9t5QdQEQoRVmqyLlRBYv6Tq-BMtrvr1x " (which I would like you to judge/comment on (take over a year if you have to, don't make it a priority. I doubt I'mgoing anywhere)) comment to be continued....

Comment: Phil C ...continued from last comment; if I were to hypothetically reverse time, and hypothetically shine infrared tachyon light onto the resistor, would it then begin to ionize the wiring it was connected to, with an electric field? I ask this, not because I want a free thermocoupler, but because I wish to understand symmetry on a deeper level, and waste heat looks asymetric to me right now, which doesn't sit right

Comment: So I sense a hole in my knowledge of thermodynamics, not just electronics. Electronics is just my comfort zone

Comment: @user179283 I've already watched much of what was in the YouTube playlist. It seemed like a good collection to get introduced to some very interesting ideas. Not sure I can meaningfully further comment. Also unfortunately can't comment on the hypothetical tachyon question with any confidence. My recommendation would be to find a physics forum that's open to these kinds of questions. On a personal level, I'll also recommend trying to narrow the focus a bit. You'll burn yourself out and get confused quickly trying to take everything in all at once. Stay curious, but pace yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks will do... that's part of the reason it took me so long, I've been getting lathargic from too much effort and too little pay-off, thanks for the honesty and advice. Glad I'm not buying into psuedo science (I did that when I was younger and dumber)

Answer (score 4):

In general adding heat to a resistor will change it's resistive property. A negative temperature coefficient resistor will have it's resistance go down with increased temperature. On the other hand a positive temperature coefficient resistor will see an increase of resistance as temperature rises.

The change of resistance does not alter the fact that the resistor is still a dissipative device that essentially raises the net entropy of the universe.

Answer (score 2):

A resistor produces an output voltage that rises with temperature. It's called "thermal noise" and is calculated as: -

\$\sqrt{4\cdot k_B\cdot T\cdot R\cdot \Delta F}\$

Where \$k_B\$ is Boltzmann's constant, T is the temperature in kelvin, R is the resistance in ohms and \$\Delta F\$ is the bandwidth of the noise you might be interested in.

See [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise) for more information and see [this calculator](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Thermal-Noise-Calculator.phtml) you can use to determine the values of RMS voltages produced.

For instance, with R = 10 giga ohm and at 500 degC (773 kelvin), over a 1 MHz bandwidth you could measure about 15 mV.